# Como eu faço um gráfico NMDS?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Eu gostaria de mostrar as espécies no gráfico de NMDS. Eu apenas consigo mostrar os pontos das comunidades em cada grupo, mas gostaria de mostrar as espécies. O meu gráfico está assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Veja se esse [link](https://jonlefcheck.net/2012/10/24/nmds-tutorial-in-r/) ajuda.

Answer (score 1):

Cheque a vinheta de introdução ao pacote vegan:

```
vignette("intro-vegan", "vegan")
```

Usando o exemplo fornecido pelo pacote:

```
library(vegan)
data(dune)
nmds <- metaMDS(dune)
plot(nmds, type = "n"); text(nmds, display = "spec")
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Se deseja usar ggplot2 para gerar os gráficos, a opção mais simples é usar o pacote ggvegan. Ele ainda está em desenvolvimento, mas pode ser instalado do GitHub:

```
library(devtools); install_github("gavinsimpson/ggvegan")
```

Ele implementa métodos de autoplot para os objetos gerados pelo vegan. No caso:

```
library(ggvegan)
autoplot(nmds, geom = "text", layers = "species")
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No estado atual de desenvolvimento, se precisa adicionar diversos outros elementos ao gráfico (como as elipses), acaba sendo mais fácil usar `plot`.

Uma terceira opção é o pacote factoextra. Ele gera ótimas visualizações para análises multivariadas de forma simples. Mas ele não possui métodos para NMDS, assim como não suporta objetos gerados pelo vegan. Mas vale à pena conhecer: http://www.sthda.com/english/rpkgs/factoextra/